# Array sorting objects by property error with strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Basically, I'm trying to [sort an array of objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript).

Say I have three objects within an array, each with a property `views`

```
var objs = [
    {
        views: '17'
    },
    {
        views: '6'
    },
    {
        views: '2'
    }
];
```

Using the sort method on the array `objs`:

```
function sortByProperty(property) {
    return function (a,b) {
        /* Split over two lines for readability */
        return (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : 
               (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}


objs.sort(sortByProperty('views'));
```

I expect `objs` to now be in the reverse order basically, however the `'17'` seems to be treated as less than `'6'` and `'2'`. I realise this is probably because of the `'1'`.

Any ideas on resolving this problem?

I realise I could iterate through each object and convert to integers - but is there a way to avoid doing that?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CY2uM/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is somewhat typed language; the `<` means alphabetical sort for strings, numeric sort for numbers. The only way is to coerce the values into numbers. Unary operator + helps here. Thus try

```
function sortByNumericProperty(property) {
    return function (a,b) {
        var av = +a[property], bv = +b[property];
        /* Split over two lines for readability */
        return (av < bv) ? -1 : 
               (av > bv) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

But generally the common idiom ([also documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort))

```
function sortByNumericProperty(property) {
    return function (a,b) {
        return a[property] - b[property];
    }
}
```

Should also work.

Comment: Performance wise, do you think it'd be better to do this vs iterating over the array and converting each property to an integer beforehand?

Comment: In this case implicit conversion is also happening.

Comment: ahren: it really should not matter too much; most of the time the difference should be neglible.

Answer (score 2):

if `a[property]` and `b[property]` can be parsed to numbers

```
function sortByProperty(property) {
    return function (a,b) {
            return a[property] - b[property];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to convert your values to integer before using it -

```
function sortByProperty(property) {
    return function (a,b) {
        var x = parseInt(a[property]);  
        var y = parseInt(b[property])
        /* Split over two lines for readability */
        return (x < y) ? -1 : (x > y) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I realise I could simply `parseInt` everything - but it's not quite what I was hoping for...